# Are there any spell guidelines for increasing size in Hermetic Magic?

Tags: ars-magica-5, ars-magica

I saw a short story written by someone who writes a Diedne blog and it mentions the mage using magic to increase size. Is this possible and are there any existing spell guidelines for it?

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly Muto Corpus 3, as in *Preternatural Growth and Shrinking*, and also and the spell *Assume the Stature of the Giants of El Cid* (MoH p.49, MuCo15). Note thoug that after the initial change the cost to continue to change size is not 1:1.

Many spells change the size of a person or creature, or creatures have their size altered to suit the story needs of an Ars Magica saga. The rationale fro the mechanics below is because +2 mags equates to a 10x times increase in overall mass (as per +2 mags for T: Group), which is demonstrated by the maximum group size being 10x individuals.

Therefore each +1 mag in spell design will add up to 3 size levels (note some spells sampled from the core books seem to use +2 levels instead, but there has been much discussion and the fair middle ground seems to be +3 size per mag).

Each +1 mag in spell design will reduce size by 6 levels (again variable by books, some spells seem to be able to reduce by a far greater amount than increase, I think that is primarily because once a creature is smaller than size -4 they have such low wound levels than it is almost moot).

Each +1 Size = +2 Strength, -1 Quickness, +1 point in the wound level damage ranges (see HoH:MC p. 39).

That means changing a soldier from normal (size +0) size to size +2 adds 4 strength, subtracts 2 quickness, and alters their first “light wound” damage range to 1-7 points instead of 1-5. That might not sound like much of a change but it makes the soldier far more offensively oriented. Slower, harder to kill, and able to inflict more damage.

This is also why reducing an opponent down to -3 or smaller is very effective, it might make them quicker but they have radically reduced wound levels for penalties, which is savage in a prolonged battle.

There is also a point at which the difference between the attacker and defender becomes so extreme that the defender really shouldn’t be able to “parry” to defend. A rationale is: A mouse can avoid the boot of a man easily due to speed, but if the man successfully steps on it, then it really should be dead, or mostly dead.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible. "Utterly change the appearance or size of a person" is a Muto Corpus level 3 effect (AM5e core, page 132). The sample spell *Preternatural Growth and Shrinking* on page 131 allows a caster to increase a human target's size by 1 or decrease it by 1 or 2 using that effect.